# jquery mobile asp new page in iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, jquery-mobile, dialog

Well I have most of the problem figured out. But there is still a slight problem. The `<iframe src=""` doesn't seem to be behaving, it won't pick up the url in my `data-popupurl="product.asp?itemid=[catalogid]`.

Anyone know why?

```
<script>
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#page1", function() {

    $(".popupInfoLink").on("click", function(){
        var url = $(this).data("popupurl");
        $( "#popupInfo iframe" ).attr("src", url);
    });

});
</script>


<a class="popupInfoLink" href="#popupInfo" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-popupurl="product.asp?itemid=[catalogid]"><img src= "/thumbnail.asp?file=[THUMBNAIL]&maxx=200&maxy=0" width="320" height="300" alt="pot" border="0" /></a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupInfo" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="d" data-tolerance="15,15" class="ui-content">
    <iframe src="" width="800px" height="800px"></iframe>
</div>
```

You can see my problem here:
https://www.kitchenova.com/mobile

Just run a search for lets say "cookie" then click on a product. A blank pop-up comes up where the `product.asp?itemid=[catalogid]` should be loading.

Comment: <a href="..." target="_blank">...

Comment: You can't use popup to show a page, but you can use a dialog for that.

Comment: ah thanks, I will now look into that, you are awesome! @Omar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQM popup widget with an iFrame.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/afBuT/)**

The link around the img now links to the popup id. I added a custom data attribute called data-popupurl that has the url for the iFrame and I added a class for a click handler as you will probably have multiple thumbnails on a page (NOTE: the data attribute could just hold the catalog id, or you could use another way to get the url):

```
<a class="popupInfoLink" href="#popupInfo" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-popupurl="http://www.houzz.com/photos/6147609/T-Fal-I-Hoffmann-Stock-Pot-8-Qt--contemporary-cookware-and-bakeware-"><img src= "http://st.houzz.com/simgs/a1419d6702561831_3-4003/contemporary-cookware-and-bakeware.jpg" width="320" height="300" alt="pot" border="0" /></a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupInfo" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="d" data-tolerance="15,15" class="ui-content">
    <iframe src="" width="400px" height="400px"></iframe>
</div>
```

The script simply responds to a click on the link by reading the url for the popup and then setting the iFrame src to that url. In your case the url would be `product.asp?itemid=[catalogid]`

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#page1", function() {    
    $(".popupInfoLink").on("click", function(){
        var url = $(this).data("popupurl");
        $( "#popupInfo iframe" ).attr("src", url);
    });    
});
```

Comment: Actually there is a slight problem. The iframe src="" is not picking up the java-script "var url". The pop-up comes up blank. I tried to add the "product.asp?itemid=[catalogid]" to the iframe src, but that only made the first thumbnail work, the rest of the thumbnails just opened the first link.

Comment: @Mr.Vegas reload `iframe` after opening the popup`. `var iframe = $("#popupInfo").find("iframe").clone(); $("#popupInfo").find("iframe").replaceWith(iframe).attr("src", url);` something like this.

Comment: @Mr.Vegas Here is an update: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/afBuT/1/ Added data-history="false" and a second item to show separate urls.  I also set url to nothing when popup closes. To do it as in the example, for each A, put data-popupurl="product.asp?itemid=[catalogid]" and the code will set the iframe correctly.

Comment: Actually its simpler than that I just switched it to `$( document ).load`.  Just needed to make the script wait till the page loads,but it seems a bit slow. Also I did not understand your explanation. How do I reload the iframe after it opens? I would like to know.

Comment: Everytime you set the src ( $( "#popupInfo iframe" ).attr("src", url); ) you are reloading the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the target attribute of the anchor (a) tag.
[Here is the W3 Schools documentation.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_anchor_target.asp)

```
<a href="product.asp?itemid=[catalogid]" target="_blank"><img src= "/thumbnail.asp?file=[THUMBNAIL]&maxx=200&maxy=0" width="320" height="300" alt="[name]" border="0"></a>
```

By the way, I strongly urge you not to do this. People don't like that, because they don't have a way of knowing that's the behavior before they do it. If people really want to open it in a new window or tab, then they can right click and do that.

Keep one question per post is the Stack Overflow policy. But the best way to learn is by jumping in and doing tutorials. Don't ask questions until you've gotten seriously stuck. Part of learning to program is learning to figure things out on your own.

Comment: I am seriously stuck I have been at for about 5 or 6 hours straight. I have visited multiple jquery forums, here, and youtube tutorials but cannot get this to work. Maybe pop-up was the wrong word to use, more like lightbox that has dynamic information loaded into it and the user can click away to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want to pop open a new window, you want a dialog frame to appear overlayed on top of your other content?

Have a look at the [PopupControlExtender](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx) from the Ajax Control Toolkit. I don't know how well it will work in a jQuery Mobile environment, but it's worth a look.

Sample code.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Btn1" Text="Click Here For More Info" />
<ajaxToolkit:PopupControlExtender ID="PopEx" runat="server" TargetControlID="Btn1" PopupControlID="Panel1" Position="Bottom" />
<asp:Panel runat="server" id="Panel1">
Here is some more info!
</asp:Panel>
```

Or since you're using jQuery Mobile, why don't you stick with what they already provide for this? Have a look at [jQuery Mobile panels](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/panel/) or [jQuery Mobile popups](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/popup/).